# Phone number regular expression

Tags: regex

I am reviewing the c# code of an application and documenting. While going through the code, I seen an unusual regular expression for US Phone Number. The regular expression is below

```
 @"^[01]?[- .]?(\([2-9]\d{2}\)|[2-9]\d{2})[- .]?\d{3}[- .]?\d{4}$";
```

My conclusion from the above phone number would be like 01.(29).123.4567 or 01-38-111-1111.

Am I interpreting correctly? Any insight into that regular expression is highly appreciated. Examples for above regular expression would help me to learn more about regular expressions.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Reading left to right...

- `^[01]?` May **possibly** start with `0` or `1`.
- `[- .]?` May **possibly** be followed with a `-`, *space*  or `.`.
- `(([2-9]\d{2})|[2-9]\d{2})` **Must** start with a digit between `2` and `9` and then be followed by any two digits. (This is strangely repeated twice, and the capturing groups should always contain the same portion, weird). This may have meant to have escaped the parenthesis, which would make more sense. Generally, you use the `\` character to escape.
- `[- .]?` May **possibly** be followed with a `-`, *space* or `.`.
- `\d{3}` **Must** be followed by any three digits.
- `[- .]?` May **possibly** be followed with a `-`, *space* or `.`.
- `\d{4}$` **Must** be followed (and end) with any four digits.

Comment: I was just about to do the exact same thing. Saved me some typing. +1 to you.  I think the "mismatched" parens are supposed to be escaped, yielding (29) or just 29, or any 2 digit number using digits 2-9. More cleary, I think this is meant (\([2-9]\d{2}\)|[2-9]\d{2})

Comment: ^[01]? how does it mean it can start with a space ?

Comment: @AdnanBhatti: Bad copy and paste. I blame the OP's lack of code formatting.

Comment: @Kibbee: That would make more sense :)

Comment: @alex Thanks for the quick reply, in your answer for some xpressions you said May possibly start or followed by, does that mean they are optional or it must have either one of those symbols? for the above expression i am quoting examples, please let me know which of those is applicable. 18001111111, 1-800-123-4567,1.800.123.4567, 8001234567,(800)-123-4567, (800)2345678. You also stated for one expression paranthesis is missing, actually its there! please correct me if i am wrong

Comment: @user951819: It means the phone number can start with `0` or `1` but doesn't have to. The part about the missing parenthesis was my fault, I didn't see the closing one.

Comment: wow, seems like SO is erasing escaped parens, lets try that again. (\([2-9]\d{2}\)|[2-9]\d{2})

Comment: Yep, it sure does erase them.

Comment: @kibbee Are you suggesting me that the regular expression is incorrect?? am I missing any parens anywhere? if yes plz guide me where to insert the parens. thnx :)

Comment: So all things up. I appreciate. And who is there with a "SINGLE REGULAR EXPRESSION for the international mobile number validation"?

Answer (score 0):

^[01]? = 0 or 1 or nothing

[-.]? = - or . or nothing

(([2-9]\d{2}) = first number 2 or greater followed by 2 digits which can be any number b/w 0 to 9 .. means 012  or 112 both will work fine

| = or sign

[2-9]\d{2}) = first number b/w 2 and 9 followed by 2 numbers b/w 0-9

[-.]? = means - or . or nothing

\d{4}= any four numbers b/w 0-9

$ = It make sure regex ended with what is preceding $ sign. ^ does same thing as $ but it checks only the beginning of the regex.

Answer (score 0):

```
^\d{2}-\d{3,15}$
```

It will help to ranging the mobile number from 3 t0 15 digits.

ex: `91-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx`

the above `x` is ranging from 3 to 15 digits
[RegularExpression(`@"^\d{2}-\d{3,15}$`", ErrorMessage = "Invalid Phone no")]

Answer (score 0):

```
[RegularExpression(@"^\d{2}-\d{10,15}$", ErrorMessage = "Invalid Phone no")]
```

it will take the number in the form of 91-xxxxxxxxxx
x is 10 to 15 numbers ranging